# Drawing a single line of cache memory

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw what a single address line of cache memory would look like.  I want to draw just one line of the diagram (one index):

[image]

How would I generate this using TikZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for [procrastination](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4267/1952)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=5mm, label=above:valid] (valid) {};
\node[draw, minimum width=20mm, minimum height=5mm, right=-\pgflinewidth of valid,, label=above:tag] (tag) {};
\node[draw, minimum width=40mm, minimum height=5mm, right=-\pgflinewidth of tag, label=above:data] (data) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```